# SQL Server 2014 (or relationships between Tables)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables :

- Table1: `Employee`
- Table2: `Gouvernement`
- Table3: `PrivateFirm`

I would like to do this relationship between this tables in SQL Server 2014 express.

- An employee can work with `Gouvernment` or `PrivateFirm`.
- An Employee can work only in one place

Can you tell me please how can I realise this thing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like homework.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to add a table called employer that will have a 1:1 relationship with both gouvernment and privateFirm and a 1:n relationship with the employee table.

Another way is to keep a nullable gov_id column and a nullable provateFirm_id column in your employee table, both foreign keys, and create a check constraint to ensure at least one of them is always null.

Comment: Thanks Zohar I ll try to do it and see what will happen